# TypeError: module.exports.v1 is not a constructor, error thrown from google-cloud/firestore when using firebase-admin sdk

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Recently I encountered the above error (TypeError: module.exports.v1 is not a constructor) when trying to run firebase-firestore related tests. Earlier I had no issue running the tests but after doing a `npm install` was getting the above error. 
The source of the error is from `google-cloud/firestore` which is required by `firebase-admin`.
Tried several options but it doesn't seems to get resolved. I then tried with an older node-module and it worked as expected.

Comment: Possibly a corrupted node_modules directory? Have you tried deleting it (and the package lock file) and reinstalling the dependencies?

Comment: yes did all the possible stuff. tried with deleting both package-lock and node-modules but the problem still exists

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to the test framework I've been using. Once I changed from jest to mocha the problem got solved.

Answer (score 1):

When I updated firebase admin sdk from 8.4.0 to higher then I had same error in running jest test code.

I fixed it to add `--env node` option for jest.

`jest --env node`

Comment: This was the fix for me 

Answer (score 1):

I hit this error when I left out an `await` on an async function. That caused my code to continue running after the jest environment had been torn down.

There was a message that said `ReferenceError: You are trying to` import `a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.` which should have been a tip that I was running async code and not waiting for completion.

Answer (score 0):

We needed to upgrade node from `v8.11.3` to `v8.16.2`.